# Getting Started with Office JS API Beta (1.6) Validation

Tags: office-js

I would like to use the office JS API to perform data validations on cells in excel, more specifically allowing a user to select data from a drop-down only. if anyone can provide me with a link to code samples that would be a great help. I know this feature is in Beta, but want to use it for a test environment.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There is a code snippet that does this. You can see it in the [Script Lab tool from AppSource](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/WA104380862?src=office&tab=Overview). In the tree of Samples, scroll down to the Preview section. Open the snippet called Data Validation.

Comment: The data validation API themselves are still in preview stage. It'll likely be few more months before it is generally available (GA). You can check the API specs [here](https://github.com/officedev/office-js-docs/tree/ExcelJs_OpenSpec)